# How to give more weights to certain words in TF-IDF model?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

To start off, I may be barking up the wrong tree as I'm very new to ML in general so please bear with me (and enlighten me if so :]).

I'm clustering my blog articles to recommend related articles to the currently viewed article using `TF-IDF` and `cosine similarity`.

It has worked well with simple word counts but I'd like to tune it more by giving some articles that are linked (as in `<a href="path-to-foo">FooArticle</a>`) to one another more weights (similar to PageRank I suppose?).

I thought of simply chugging the linked article names into TF vectors but it doesn't seem right.

How should I go about doing this?

Should I be making another model (possibly different algorithm?) specially for these and combine via `z-score` or something?

Overall, I'm pretty lost. Can anyone help?

Edit:

Here is the code taken (using scala & spark mllib):

```
val LinkedArticleTitleRegex = """(?<!http|https)^(\w+)$""".r
val hashingTF = new HashingTF()

import collection.JavaConverters._

val docs = articles.map(a => Jsoup.parse(a.content.body))

val tfidfVectors: RDD[Vector] = {
  val tfVectors = docs.map { doc =>
    val words = doc.select("p, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6").text()
      .replace("\n", " ")
      .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "") // only keep words and space
      .split(" ")
      .toVector
      .map(_.trim.toLowerCase)
      .filter(s => s.nonEmpty && !stopwords.contains(s)) // filter stop words and empty spaces

    hashingTF.transform(words)
  }

  val idfModel = new IDF().fit(tfVectors)

  idfModel.transform(tfVectors)
}

val linkedArticleTitles: RDD[List[String]] = docs.map(doc =>
  doc.select("a[href]").asScala
    .map(_.attr("href"))
    .collect { case LinkedArticleTitleRegex(articleTitle) => articleTitle }
    .toList
)
```

There are currently two feature sets (`tfidfVectors` based on word counts and `linkedArticleTitles`) and I'd like to combine them while giving more weights to `linkedArticleTitles` feature set.

Comment: You could just keep track of which articles were linked where and artifically add a certain factor to your TF-IDF score. No harm in that.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Thanks. Could you elaborate more on **add a certain factor to your TF-IDF score**? Would the best way to do so using `z-score`?

Comment: Explaining how to do it beyond this would require actually seeing your current approach in code. If you're using `scikit-learn`, it'll be more difficult than if you wrote your own implementation. Please post a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, and we can help more.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan I've updated the answer with code sample. Please advise :]

Comment: I had been assuming you were writing your own implementation. Using Apache Spark and Scala makes it harder for the approach I was thinking of, since you'd have to figure out how to subclass and overwrite their member methods. Sorry. :(

Comment: @AkshatMahajan That's okay. But do you mind still explaining the approach that you were thinking of (if I were to write my implementation?) or perhaps some keywords that I can google up? I just need some guidance where to look. Thanks :]